# Disable Media Control Overlay in Firefox 89.0.1 *Without* Disabling Hardware Media Control (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, firefox, keyboard, media

Toggling `media.hardwaremediakeys.enabled` disables the actual hardware media control option.
I would like to be able to control media outputted by Firefox from my keyboard, but without getting that annoying overlay that keeps me from reading stuff behind it. Might be useful to some, but not to me.
Thank you in advance for any help.

P.S. Again, I'm using Firefox 89.0.1 on Windows 10, 64 bit. Don't hesitate in asking for any more system details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find how to do this, so I created a [utility](https://github.com/qt-kaneko/remosd) that hides the media part of the Windows 10 volume control (system wide), maybe it will be useful to you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).